# Google play services conflict with admob

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob

Unity3d 5.1.2.
I'm trying to integrate ads and leaderboards into my game. I import the admob package and then when I start to i import the google-play-services package, the following error is shown:

```
Error importing folder (The pathName assets/plugins is already mapped to 21c47ce8563684fe3a95a29ca1a7aa32. But the meta data wants it to be mapped to fce8a713f1e5a4cc4b9973d1ef630f31)
```

Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may happen if you remove any file from disk directly, because it will not delete the meta file associated to that file. To resolve this just hit reimport all in assets menu, it will create and map new meta file automatically

Comment: I spent 5 frustrating days. Now thanks to you, i can publish game with leaderboards feature.

Comment: It was shortlived however. I could import both plugins, but when i tried to build, i got the error: Assets\Plugins\Android\MainLibProj' is missing AndroidManifest.xml file.
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()